# Spring Form Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name order available

Tags: forms, spring

I have create a Spring form like this:

index.jsp

```
<a href="/Spring_MVC/order.jsp">Order</a>
```

Order.jsp

```
<form:form action="createOrder" method="Post" modelAttribute="order">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Order ID:
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="order.orderId"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>
                    Product Name: 
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="order.productName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr> 

        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Order.java:

```
public class Order {

    private String orderId;
    private String productName;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Order() {


    }

    public Order(String orderId, String productName) {
        super();
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
}
```

OrderController.java:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName());

    /**
     * 
     */
    public OrderController() {
        super();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createOrder", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createOrder(@ModelAttribute("order")Order order, BindingResult result) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Order ID: " + order.getOrderId());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Product Name: " + order.getProductName());

        // Implementation validator

        // Data Binding the form properties to Order field
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Error in Binding Result");
        }

        return "/order";
    }
}
```

I get the Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name order available. Is it i need to create a bean name order using GET and pass to the web first before POST back to server.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your JSP page.

You have used the field names wrongly in the path attribute of the input tag.

it should be like this.

```
 <form:input path="orderId"/>
```

Hope this helps you.
Cheers.

Comment: I try that but it does not work either. I click on the link on the index.jsp as above and throw the IllegalStateException. Please help.

Comment: Where is the GET request mapping to show the form?? There also you need to define the ModelAttribute and also remove the **"order"** from @ModelAttribute.

Comment: I do not have any GET request mapping that show the form rather than a HTML link <a href="" />.

Comment: I using this <a href="/showOrder">Order</a> and @RequestMapping(value = "/showOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView showOrder(@ModelAttribute Order order) {
  return new ModelAndView("/order", "order", order);
 } but the showOrder method in controller does not get called because of this mapping. How i need to change in HTML?

Comment: Is ther any alternative method to invoke controler other than using HTML form? Because i find the submit button is quite ugly.

Comment: No for GET request submit button is not needed. I need to see the controller GET function to show the order form.

Comment: My Form is like this <code> <form name="/showOrder" action="/Spring_MVC/showOrder" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Order"></input>
 </form> </code> and my controller get request is like this: <code> // Get Request to show the form
 @RequestMapping(value = "/showOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView showOrder(@ModelAttribute Order order) {
  return new ModelAndView("/order", "order", order);
 }</code>

Comment: How to invoke GET reqeust in controller without using form?

Comment: See. When you call the url with the href it will generate get request and in your controller you need to create one function that is mapped with the same url and also make that as RequestMethod.GET.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11979/discussion-between-peterwkc-and-japs)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag), your `path` attribute inside the `input` tag should not include the model attribute name `order`; e.g.:

```
<form:input path="orderId" />
```